# Does a coin tossing algorithm terminate?

Tags: algorithms, randomized-algorithms

Suppose we have an algorithm like:

```
n = 0
REPEAT
  c = randomInt(0,1)
  n = n + 1
UNTIL (c == 0)
RETURN n
```

(Assumuing the random number generator produces "good" random numbers in the mathematical sense.)

I understand that there is no number $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that the algorithm is guaranteed to terminate after fewer than $n$ steps. However, the probability of terminating after *some* finite number of steps is 1.

Is there a convention among computer scientists to call an algorithm like this either "terminating" or "non-terminating"?

Comment: Possibly related: http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/26252/random-algorithm-termination

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The formal, unambiguous way to state this is “terminates with probability 1” or “terminates [almost surely](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_surely)”. In probability theory, “almost” means “with probability 1”.

For a [probabilistic Turing machine](http://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Probabilistic_Turing_machine#Complexity_Theory_of_Probabilistic_Turing_Machines), termination is defined as “terminates always” (i.e. whatever the random sequence is), not as “terminates with probability 1”. This definition makes decidability by a probabilistic Turing machine equivalent to decidability by a deterministic Turing machine supplied with an infinite tape of random bits — PTM are mostly interesting in complexity theory. In applied CS, though, computations that always give the correct result but terminate only with probability 1 are a lot more useful than computations that may return an incorrect result.